# System.net.websocket ClientWebSocket with self signed certificate

Tags: .net, websocket, mono

I am trying to use a `ClientWebSocket` to connect to a secure websocket that uses a self signed certificate. The assembly was built for the latest version of .NET framework and is being run via mono on a linux system.

On connect, i get the exception `Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED`

I have tried messing with `ClientWebSocketOptions` and `ServicePointManager`, but this has had no effect.

How would i get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I know I am a bit late to the party, but I think you are the victim of this bug:
https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/8660
While both ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback and ClientWebSocketOptions.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback are available, they do not get used on mono.